# Leveling in Neverwinter

Tags: neverwinter

Playing as a level 69 Drow Trickster Rogue, how do I get to level 70 the quickest? i'm at Spinward Rise, and i really don't want to keep doing the quests over and over, because that's not fun for me. But I want to unlock the next step in the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Find the best way to do this is guild quests.
They can produce a massive amount of XP in a short space of time. I only recently started playing and have 3 Characters at level 70 now, I mainly jump from level 40 to level 50 odd just on following the guild quests. 
Skirmishes, Dungeons and PvP can also provide you with a fun way to gain XP as well as some decent AD.